# socket.io show multiple users data after click

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have this code here:

server:

```
   io.emit('attack-damage', {
   damage: damage,
   attacker: username,
   });
```

client:

```
socket.on('attack-damage', (data) => {
     setTimeout(() => this.damageVisible = false, 1000);
});
```

What it does is when user clicks `attack` it emits and shows damage of the user that fades away after one second. Problem is that let's say if I click attack my damage is being shown but also if another player clicks attack then it's damage is being shown and mine damage fades out faster than after 1 second it just replaces the new damage from another player. How to show multiple damages on the screen and not just one ?

**EDIT**

```
        socket.on('attack-damage', (data) => {
            this.damage = data.damage;
            this.aryDamage.push(data.damage, data.attacker);
                if (!this.bolDamageRunning) {
                    if(this.aryDamage.length != 0) {
                        this.bolDamageRunning = true;
                        setTimeout(() => {
                              this.damageVisible = false;

                              this.aryDamage.splice(0,1);
                              this.bolDamageRunning = false;
                        }, 2000);

                    } else {

                    }
                } else {

                }

            setTimeout(() => this.damageVisible = true, 2000);
```

When I use above code it makes appear damage after two seconds after the click. But also if I use two users, then old damage from screen is being replaced with new one

Answer (score 1):

1. create a global array called aryDamage.
2. create a global boolean called bolDamageRunning.
3. client socket.on('attack-damage'), add a new element to the array, e.g.

```
aryDamage.push(data);
```

4. create a timer using setInterval to read the aryDamage every 100 ms.

```
function thisTimerCalledEvery100MS() {
  // run Damage only when last Damage finish
  if (!bolDamageRunning) {
    // Check whether another damage waiting
    if (aryDamage.length != 0) {
      // Set running true
      bolDamageRunning = true;

      // call funDamage after 1 second
      setTimeout(funDamage, 1000);
    } else {
      // No command waiting, do nothing
    }
  } else {
    // Another command running, do nothing
  }
}

function funDamage() {
  // Your code to show damange, or
  // do something with the first element of aryDamage
  this.damageVisible = false;


  // remove top element from aryDamage
  aryDamage.splice(0,1);


  // Set running = false
  bolDamageRunning = false;
}
```

This technique makes sure the last 'Command' finishes before executing next 'Command'.

Comment: Ty, but I'm having hard time implementing this through VueJS

Comment: `this.damageVisible = false;` when to set it to true ?

Comment: where is no.4 in my answer?  you need another setinterval timer to handle the 'command queue', not handle it inside socket.on